# Google App Engine using old settings after deployment (AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS from settings.py)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, deployment, django-settings

I have a djangoappengine project and my latest deployment is returning the following error:

```
Error importing authentication backend myapp.dashboard.authentication.DashboardAuthentication:
"No module named authentication"
```

the project did initially use this authentication backend, but I've updated it to remove that from settings and define a different authentication backend.

Old settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'myapp.dashboard.authentication.DashboardAuthentication',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' 
)
```

New settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'new_auth_package.authentication.DashboardAuthentication',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)
```

**File References**

I believe that my settings.py file is being successfully deployed with its changes because if I change debug to False and redeploy I get the more obscure 500 error.

I've searched my entire project for anywhere that I might have referenced the old auth backend other than in settings.py and there's nothing.

Is it possible that appengine caches references to my auth backends regardless of what settings.py says?

**Versions**

I tried deploying a version 2 and updating my default version to point to it, but the problem persists.

Mystifyingly, if I access the app at 1.myapp.appspot.com and at 2.myapp.appspot.com it uses the correct authentication for both versions. But browsing to the default myapp.appspot.com still gives me this error regardless of which version I set to default.

Is there something I'm missing where I've accidentally told appengine to cache things? Or is there some way I can force a reset to get rid of that reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication backend that was used to log you in is stored in your session. So if you log in, then remove it and deploy, the system will error on trying to find your user based on your session.

Solution: clear your session.